# zipfile.ZipFile.extractall() missing required argument: 'self'

Tags: python, zip

according to [docs.python.org/3/](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall) its enough if i supply one argument - "path"

```py
zipfile.ZipFile.extractall(path="./"+repo['tag_name']+".zip")
# path is equal to "./v0.1.zip"
```

it throwed an error that says I need to pass another argument named "self".

```
zipfile.ZipFile.extractall(path="./"+repo['tag_name']+".zip")
TypeError: extractall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

What is self? I can't understand it's purpose and how classes work.

Comment: You have to create an instance of `ZipFile` and operate on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most Python classes, this one requires you to create an instance, then use its methods.

```py
z = zipfile.ZipFile(repo['tag_name'] + ".zip")
z.extractall()
z.close()
```

You can condense this into a single line if you want to, but then you don't have access to the created object (`z` above) after this finishes. (For example, you can't call its `.close()` method, which is really mandatory according to the documentation, though I can't imagine that it really matters if you are only reading from the zip file.)

```py
zipfile.ZipFile(repo['tag_name'] + ".zip").extractall()
```

The `path` argument to `extractall` says where to extract the members *to* (if you omit it, they will be extracted to the current directory), and is distinct from the input file name used in the constructor.

Classes and objects are just a distraction when you are doing something really simple, but they help organize any nontrivial code; when you have several `zip` files open, each one has its own object instance which keeps track of the individual metadata for each (which file, what members, the password, etc).

Answer (score 1):

This is the sample code you could try.
zip ref object should be created first to use the instance.

```
import zipfile
zip_ref=zipfile.ZipFile("./ProcessExplorer.zip","r")
zip_ref.extractall(".")
zip_ref.close()
```